# Prove that $\forall m,n\in\Bbb N : \frac{1}{\sqrt[m]{1+n}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt[n]{1+m}}\ge1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

How would you prove the following inequality:

$\forall m,n\in\Bbb N : \frac{1}{\sqrt[m]{1+n}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt[n]{1+m}}\ge1$

Your help is appreciated!

Comment: @FriederJäckel I tried comparing the two fractions to 1/2 but I wasn't able to get anything conclusive. Induction would be no good as this inequality is dependent of 2 unrelated variables. Raising the whole thing to power got me nowhere, too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the generalised Bernoulli inequality we get
$(1+n)^{1/m}\leq 1+\frac{n}{m}$ and $(1+m)^{1/n}\leq 1+\frac{m}{n}.$ Putting this together we conclude
\begin{equation}\frac{1}{\sqrt[m]{1+n}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt[n]{1+m}}\geq (1+\frac{n}{m})^{-1}+(1+\frac{n}{m})^{-1}=\frac{m}{m+n}+\frac{n}{m+n}=1.
\end{equation}

Comment: Oh wow, I hadn't thought about that. Thank you!